# jquery direct messages to users

Tags: php, jquery

I am really new to jquery and I am wondering how do I can send a message to all users there are on my website without they need to refresh the page.

Like, I have a form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="msg">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Now I want for example to enter "Hello." and then I click send. Then the message should appear on all users that currently are on my website, but without refreshing there page.

Is this possible?

Comment: [`Node.JS`](https://nodejs.org/en/) & [`Socket.IO`](http://socket.io/)

Comment: if you want that to happen real time, use Nodejs and Socket IO as mentioned above. If time is not an issue, then create a text file which you can update (write) from server side and read it from client using jquery get https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ in combination with setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Check out : [Pusher](https://pusher.com), [Pubnub](https://pubnub.com), [Firebase](https://firebase.com), or [Socket.IO](https://socket.io)

They will help you get started with real-time logic fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this only with jQuery. jQuery is only javascript framework running in client PC. You can achieve your goal in several ways. For example you can save your message from form into database via PHP. In client side you need to check (every 10 seconds for example) database (jQuery - Ajax ) if there are changes (against datetime for example) then you will reload div and show it to users.
This is only one way how can you do this. There are other ways of course. Node.JS, Socket.IO are great tools for do this more easily :)